# Instantiating prefab from resources at run time for endless runner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate prefabs on run time for creating end less runner ,problem I'm having is with positioning the new prefab ,I want to instantiate the new prefab right where the first one ends,not where the existing prefab is there, help will be appreciated ,I tried googling but I'm just a beginner need a clear and basic idea,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would consider the first item is positioned at (0,0,0) and all platform are the same:

```
Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;
void AddPrefab(){
   GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab);
   this.previousPosition.x += obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
   obj.transform.position = this.previousPosition;
}
```

if you use different platform sizes, then you would have to store the previous added, then get half of that one and half of the new one and add this to the position.